# maximum call stack size exceeded - no apparent recursion

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, recursion, callstack

I've spent about 12 hours looking through this code, and fiddling with it, trying to find out where there's a recursion problem because I'm getting the, "maximum call stack size exceeded," error, and haven't found it. Someone smarter than me please help me!

so far, all I found was that when I make the object, `spot`, a `circle`, object, the problem disappears, but when I make it a, 'pip', I get this stack overflow error. I've gone over the pip class with a friggin' microscope, and still have no idea why this is happening!

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Classes
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//=====================================================================================
//CLASS - point
function point(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
//=====================================================================================
// CLASS - drawableItem
function drawableItem() {
    var size = 0;
    this.center = new point(0,0);
    this.lineWidth = 1;
    this.dependentDrawableItems = new Array();
}
//returns the size
drawableItem.prototype.getSize = function getSize(){
    return this.size;
}
// changes the size of this item and the relative size of all dependents
drawableItem.prototype.changeSize = function(newSize){
    var relativeItemSizes = new Array;
    relativeItemSizes.length = this.dependentDrawableItems.length;
    // get the relative size of all dependent items
    for (var i = 0; i < this.dependentDrawableItems.length; i++){
        relativeItemSizes[i] = this.dependentDrawableItems[i].getSize() / this.size;
    }
    // change the size
    this.size = newSize;
    // apply the ratio of change back to all dependent items
    for (var i = 0; i < relativeItemSizes.length; i++){
        this.dependentDrawableItems[i].changeSize(relativeItemSizes[i] * newSize);
    }
}
//moves all the vertices and every dependent to an absolute point based on center
drawableItem.prototype.moveTo = function(moveX,moveY){
    //record relative coordinates
    var relativeItems = new Array;
    relativeItems.length = this.dependentDrawableItems.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < relativeItems.length; i++){
        relativeItems[i] = new point;
        relativeItems[i].x = this.dependentDrawableItems[i].center.x - this.center.x;
        relativeItems[i].y = this.dependentDrawableItems[i].center.y - this.center.y;
    }
    //move the center
    this.center.x = moveX;
    this.center.y = moveY;
    //move all the items relative to the center
    for (var i = 0; i < relativeItems.length; i++){
        this.dependentDrawableItems[i].moveItemTo(this.center.x + relativeItems[i].x,
            this.center.y + relativeItems[i].y);
    }
}
// draws every object in dependentDrawableItems
drawableItem.prototype.draw = function(ctx){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.dependentDrawableItems.length; i++) {
        this.dependentDrawableItems[i].draw(ctx);
    }
}

//=====================================================================================
//CLASS - circle
function circle(isFilledCircle){
    drawableItem.call(this);
    this.isFilled = isFilledCircle
}
circle.prototype = new drawableItem();
circle.prototype.parent = drawableItem.prototype;
circle.prototype.constructor = circle;
circle.prototype.draw = function(ctx){
    ctx.moveTo(this.center.x,this.center.y);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.center.x, this.center.y, this.size, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.outlineColor;
    if (this.isFilled === true){
        ctx.fill();
    }else {
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    this.parent.draw.call(this,ctx);
}

//=====================================================================================
//CLASS - pip
function pip(size){
    circle.call(this,true);
}
pip.prototype = new circle(false);
pip.prototype.parent = circle.prototype;
pip.prototype.constructor = pip;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Objects/variables - top layer is last (except drawable area is first)
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
var drawableArea = new drawableItem();

var spot = new pip();
spot.changeSize(20);
drawableArea.dependentDrawableItems[drawableArea.dependentDrawableItems.length] = spot;

//------------------------------------------
// Draw loop
//------------------------------------------
function drawScreen() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
    context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    spot.moveTo(context.canvas.width/2, context.canvas.height/2);

    drawableArea.draw(context);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', drawScreen);
```

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DSU8w/

Comment: Not yet good enough for an answer, but I have a sneaking suspicion you have some non-constructors trying to act as constructors. Google closure throws some fits about `Property getSize never defined` and some functions not being a constructor! Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5991265/588079 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4613017/588079 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6095530/588079. See if that helps, otherwise try to cut parts of the code until you have the bare minimum that gives this overflow and share it in a fiddle please.

Comment: ***WARNING*** (for fellow experts): this snippet can crash your browser (crashed mine twice), so don't fiddle around with it if you have important stuff open/nonbackuped (other jsfiddle for example). @jgrant: try not to make the fiddle run automatically but after a clear user-action like a button-click, thus giving people a chance to actually load the fiddle and inspect the source before it crashes onload.

Comment: I guess that "drawableItem.prototype.changeSize" caused your problem.

Comment: @GitaarLAB - the getSize error was coming from a missing method that I deleted, along with hundreds of other lines of code in an attempt to cut the code down to bare minimum<br/><br/>

Aadit - Thanks for adding the fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> this.parent.draw.call(this,ctx);
> ```

is your problem. On a `pip` object, the parent will be `circle.prototype`. So when you now call `spot.draw()`, it will call `spot.parent.draw.call(spot)`, where `this.parent` is still the `circle.prototype`…

You will need to explicitly invoke `drawableItem.prototype.draw.call(this)` from `circle.prototype.draw`. Btw, you should [not use `new` for the prototype chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572).

Comment: I started looking into why not to use, 'new', and alternatives... and now my brain is melting.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you write code like that? It's so difficult to understand and debug. When I'm creating lots of classes I usually use [`augment`](https://github.com/javascript/augment) to structure my code. This is how I would rewrite your code:

```
var Point = Object.augment(function () {
    this.constructor = function (x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };
});
```

Using `augment` you can create classes cleanly. For example your `drawableItem` class could be restructured as follows:

```
var DrawableItem = Object.augment(function () {
    this.constructor = function () {
        this.size = 0;
        this.lineWidth = 1;
        this.dependencies = [];
        this.center = new Point(0, 0);
    };

    this.changeSize = function (toSize) {
        var fromSize = this.size;
        var ratio = toSize / fromSize;
        this.size = toSize;

        var dependencies = this.dependencies;
        var length = dependencies.length;
        var index = 0;

        while (index < length) {
            var dependency = dependencies[index++];
            dependency.changeSize(dependency.size * ratio);
        }
    };

    this.moveTo = function (x, y) {
        var center = this.center;
        var dx = x - center.x;
        var dy = y - center.y;
        center.x = x;
        center.y = y;

        var dependencies = this.dependencies;
        var length = dependencies.length;
        var index = 0;

        while (index < length) {
            var dependency = dependencies[index++];
            var center = dependency.center;

            dependency.moveTo(center.x + dx, center.y + dy);
        }
    };

    this.draw = function (context) {
        var dependencies = this.dependencies;
        var length = dependencies.length;
        var index = 0;

        while (index < length) dependencies[index++].draw(context);
    };
});
```

Inheritance is also very simple. For example you can restructure your `circle` and `pip` classes as follows:

```
var Circle = DrawableItem.augment(function (base) {
    this.constructor = function (filled) {
        base.constructor.call(this);
        this.filled = filled;
    };

    this.draw = function (context) {
        var center = this.center;
        var x = center.x;
        var y = center.y;

        context.moveTo(x, y);

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, this.size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.closePath();

        context.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
        context[this.filled ? "fill" : "stroke"]();
        base.draw.call(this, context);
    };
});

var Pip = Circle.augment(function (base) {
    this.constructor = function () {
        base.constructor.call(this, true);
    };
});
```

Now that you've created all your classes you can finally get down to the drawing:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var drawableArea = new DrawableItem;
    var spot = new Pip;

    spot.changeSize(20);
    drawableArea.dependencies.push(spot);
    window.addEventListener("resize", drawScreen, false);

    drawScreen();

    function drawScreen() {
        var width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        spot.moveTo(width / 2, height / 2);
        drawableArea.draw(context);
    }
}, false);
```

We're done. See the demo for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/b5vNk/

Not only have we made your code more readable, understandable and maintainable but we have also solved your recursion problem.

As Bergi mentioned the problem was with the statement `this.parent.draw.call(this,ctx)` in the `circle.prototype.draw` function. Since `spot.parent` is `circle.prototype` the `this.parent.draw.call(this,ctx)` statement is equivalent to `circle.prototype.draw.call(this,ctx)`. As you can see the `circle.prototype.draw` function now calls itself recursively until it exceeds the maximum recursion depth and throws an error.

The `augment` library solves this problem elegantly. Instead of having to create a `parent` property on every prototype when you augment a class `augment` provides you the `prototype` of that class as a argument (we call it `base`):

```
var DerivedClass = BaseClass.augment(function (base) {
    console.log(base === BaseClass.prototype); // true
});
```

The `base` argument should be treated as a constant. Because it's a constant `base.draw.call(this, context)` in the `Circle` class above will always be equivalent to `DrawableItem.prototype.draw.call(this, context)`. Hence you will never have unwanted recursion. Unlike `this.parent` the `base` argument will alway point to the correct prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Bergi's answer is correct, if you don't want to hard code the parent name multiple times you could use a helper function to set up inheritance:

```
function inherits(Child,Parent){
  Child.prototype=Object.create(Parent.prototype);
  Child.parent=Parent.prototype;
  Child.prototype.constructor=Child;
};
function DrawableItem() {
  this.name="DrawableItem";
}
DrawableItem.prototype.changeSize = function(newSize){
  console.log("changeSize from DrawableItem");
  console.log("invoking object is:",this.name);
}
function Circle(isFilledCircle){
    Circle.parent.constructor.call(this);
    this.name="Circle";//override name
}
inherits(Circle,DrawableItem);
Circle.prototype.changeSize = function(newSize){
  Circle.parent.changeSize.call(this);
  console.log("and some more from circle");
};
function Pip(size){
    Pip.parent.constructor.call(this,true);
    this.name="Pip";
}
inherits(Pip,Circle);

var spot = new Pip();
spot.changeSize();
```

For a polyfill on Object.create look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill).